# Pylint issue installation with windows and python 3.2

Tags: python, windows, pip

I got that issue when i try installing pylint on windows with pip, and i really have no idea from where it comes from.

```
    C:\Python33\Scripts>pip.exe install pylint
    Downloading/unpacking pylint

      Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pylint/
      URLs to search for versions for pylint:
      * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pylint/
      Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pylint/

    ...

    byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py to utils.cpython-33.pyc

    byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-33.pyc

    byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pylint\__pkginfo__.py to __pkginfo__.cpython-33.pyc

    error: The system cannot find the file specified


    running 2to3 on C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pylint\test

    ----------------------------------------

    Cleaning up...

      Removing temporary dir c:\windows\temp\pip_build_abrow198...
    Command C:\Python33\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\windows\\temp\\pip_build_abrow198\\pylint\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\windows\temp\pip-cq0pam-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\windows\temp\pip_build_abrow198\pylint
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of c:\windows\temp\pip-cq0pam-record\install-record.txt if it exists?

Comment: There is nothing there, but i tried installing with tar.gz folder directly, i got same error ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an error in the setup scripts for both Pylint and its dependency logilab-common. I encounter the error when building with `pip install pylint` or `python setup.py install`.

The error generally looks like this, and occurs right after `.pyc` files are byte-compiled:

```
error: The system cannot find the file specified
running 2to3 on C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pylint\test
```

Simply making sure that `2to3.py` is available on PATH doesn't seem to be sufficient; 2to3 itself will run, but Pylint won't install.

I just spent a bit trying to get this working, and found two promising suggestions:

First option, create a custom bat file so that 2to3 is effectively on your PATH (see [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787849/python-easy-install-pylint-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified), [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/51/building-pylint-windows-installer-for)). I managed to get `2to3` running as a bare command in both PowerShell and CMD, but couldn't get Pylint to install. Someone else might have more luck with this.

Second option, install different versions of Pylint and logilab-common which invoke 2to3 through distutils instead of on the command line (see [unmerged pull request](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/logilab-common/pull-request/2/setuppy-dont-call-2to3-directly/diff)). This worked immediately for me.

BitBucket lists that pull request as "open" since October. I don't know when it might be merged, or how long after that changes might be live on PyPI.