# Pylint installation failed on windows

Tags: python, windows, pylint

I tried to install pylint on windows (using visual studio code). I have this exception, I can't find a solution. 
I already tried to completely reinstall python but I have the exact same error. 
On other PC, the same repro step works fine.

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python" -m pip install pylint
Collecting pylint
  Downloading pylint-1.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (644kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 645kB 1.9MB/s
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32" (from pylint)
  Downloading colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid>=1.5.1 (from pylint)
  Downloading astroid-1.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (269kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 4.1MB/s
Collecting isort>=4.2.5 (from pylint)
  Downloading isort-4.2.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 5.7MB/s
Collecting mccabe (from pylint)
  Downloading mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from pylint)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lazy-object-proxy (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint)
  Downloading lazy_object_proxy-1.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Collecting wrapt (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint)
  Downloading wrapt-1.10.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: colorama, six, lazy-object-proxy, wrapt, astroid, isort, mccabe, pylint
  Running setup.py install for wrapt ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

Do you have any what the problem could be?

EDIT:
As Shankar said, I installed astroid manually. It didn't work the first time. I encountered this issue: [python easy_install pylint Error: The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787849/python-easy-install-pylint-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified#20232909)
The installation finally worked but nothing changed for pylint.

Here is the log I receive when I try to run pylint

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_modu
le_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pylint.exe\__main__.py", line
 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py"
, line 12, in run_pylint
    from pylint.lint import Run
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", li
ne 43, in <module>
    import astroid
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\__init__.py
", line 57, in <module>
    from astroid.nodes import *
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\nodes.py",
line 30, in <module>
    from astroid.node_classes import (
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\node_classe
s.py", line 26, in <module>
    from astroid import decorators
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\decorators.
py", line 12, in <module>
    import wrapt
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\wrapt\__init__.py",
 line 4, in <module>
    from .wrappers import (ObjectProxy, CallableObjectProxy, FunctionWrapper,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrapt.wrappers'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install

Pylint requires astroid package (the later the better).

```
https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid
```

Installation should be as simple as

python -m pip install astroid

Pylint requires isort package (the later the better).

```
https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort
```

Installation should be as simple as

python -m pip install isort

If you want to install from a source distribution, extract the tarball and run the following commands

python setup.py install

You’ll have to install dependencies in a similar way. For debian and rpm packages, use your usual tools according to your Linux distribution.

More information about installation and available distribution format may be found in the user manual in the doc subdirectory.

After these two dependencies installed , try installing pylint again.

Comment: The isort dependency has been installed correctly but the astroid dependency generate the exception I have put in the question.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/packages/15/ef/1c01161c40ce08451254125935c5bca85b08913e610a4708760ee1432fa8/astroid-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=e74430dfbbe09cd18ef75bd76f95425a Download and extract and then run: python setup.py install

Comment: Done, but nothing changed. I have added some additional information in the first post. Thanks for your help!